# How to fix 'Expected object of scalar type Float but got scalar type Double for argument #4 'mat1''?

Tags: pytorch, lstm

I am trying to build an lstm model. My model code is below.

My input has 4 features, Sequence length of 5 and batch size of 32.

```py
        class RNN(nn.Module):

            def __init__(self, feature_dim, output_size, hidden_dim, n_layers, dropout=0.5):
                """
                Initialize the PyTorch RNN Module
                :param feature_dim: The number of input dimensions of the neural network
                :param output_size: The number of output dimensions of the neural network      
                :param hidden_dim: The size of the hidden layer outputs
                :param dropout: dropout to add in between LSTM/GRU layers
                """
                super(RNN, self).__init__()

                # set class variables
                self.output_size = output_size
                self.n_layers = n_layers
                self.hidden_dim = hidden_dim

                # define model layers
                self.lstm = nn.LSTM(feature_dim, hidden_dim, n_layers, batch_first=True)

                self.fc = nn.Linear(hidden_dim, output_size)

                self.dropout = nn.Dropout(dropout)


            def forward(self, nn_input, hidden):
                """
                Forward propagation of the neural network
                :param nn_input: The input to the neural network
                :param hidden: The hidden state        
                :return: Two Tensors, the output of the neural network and the latest hidden state
                """

                # Get Batch Size  
                batch_size = nn_input.size(0)

                # Pass through LSTM layer
                lstm_out, hidden = self.lstm(nn_input, hidden)
                # Stack up LSTM outputs
                lstm_out = lstm_out.contiguous().view(-1, self.hidden_dim)
                # Add dropout and pass through fully connected layer
                x = self.dropout(lstm_out)
                x = self.fc(lstm_out)

                # reshape to be batch_size first
                output = x.view(batch_size, -1, self.output_size)
                # get last batch of labels
                out = output[:, -1]

                # return one batch of output word scores and the hidden state
                return out, hidden


            def init_hidden(self, batch_size):
                '''
                Initialize the hidden state of an LSTM/GRU
                :param batch_size: The batch_size of the hidden state
                :return: hidden state of dims (n_layers, batch_size, hidden_dim)
                '''
                # Implement function

                # initialize   state with zero weights, and move to GPU if available
                weight = next(self.parameters()).data

                if is_gpu_available:
                    hidden = (weight.new(self.n_layers, batch_size, self.hidden_dim).zero_().to(device),
                          weight.new(self.n_layers, batch_size, self.hidden_dim).zero_().to(device))
                else:
                    hidden = (weight.new(self.n_layers, batch_size, self.hidden_dim).zero_(),
                              weight.new(self.n_layers, batch_size, self.hidden_dim).zero_())
                return hidden
```

When I train, I got the error

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
    /usr/local/bin/kernel-launchers/python/scripts/launch_ipykernel.py in <module>
          3 
          4 # training the model
    ----> 5 trained_rnn = train_rnn(rnn, batch_size, optimizer, num_epochs, show_every_n_batches)
          6 
          7 # saving the trained model

    /usr/local/bin/kernel-launchers/python/scripts/launch_ipykernel.py in train_rnn(rnn, batch_size, optimizer, n_epochs, show_every_n_batches)
         18 
         19             # forward, back prop
    ---> 20             loss, hidden = forward_back_prop(rnn, optimizer, inputs, labels, hidden)
         21             # record loss
         22             batch_losses.append(loss)

    /usr/local/bin/kernel-launchers/python/scripts/launch_ipykernel.py in forward_back_prop(rnn, optimizer, inp, target, hidden)
         22 
         23     # get the output from the model
    ---> 24     output, h = rnn(inp, h)
         25 
         26    # calculate the loss and perform backprop

    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in __call__(self, *input, **kwargs)
        491             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
        492         else:
    --> 493             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
        494         for hook in self._forward_hooks.values():
        495             hook_result = hook(self, input, result)

    /usr/local/bin/kernel-launchers/python/scripts/launch_ipykernel.py in forward(self, nn_input, hidden)
         36 
         37         # Pass through LSTM layer
    ---> 38         lstm_out, hidden = self.lstm(nn_input, hidden)
         39         # Stack up LSTM outputs
         40         lstm_out = lstm_out.contiguous().view(-1, self.hidden_dim)

    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in __call__(self, *input, **kwargs)
        491             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
        492         else:
    --> 493             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
        494         for hook in self._forward_hooks.values():
        495             hook_result = hook(self, input, result)

    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/rnn.py in forward(self, input, hx)
        557             return self.forward_packed(input, hx)
        558         else:
    --> 559             return self.forward_tensor(input, hx)
        560 
        561 

    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/rnn.py in forward_tensor(self, input, hx)
        537         unsorted_indices = None
        538 
    --> 539         output, hidden = self.forward_impl(input, hx, batch_sizes, max_batch_size, sorted_indices)
        540 
        541         return output, self.permute_hidden(hidden, unsorted_indices)

    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/rnn.py in forward_impl(self, input, hx, batch_sizes, max_batch_size, sorted_indices)
        520         if batch_sizes is None:
        521             result = _VF.lstm(input, hx, self._get_flat_weights(), self.bias, self.num_layers,
    --> 522                               self.dropout, self.training, self.bidirectional, self.batch_first)
        523         else:
        524             result = _VF.lstm(input, batch_sizes, hx, self._get_flat_weights(), self.bias,

    RuntimeError: Expected object of scalar type Float but got scalar type Double for argument #4 'mat1'
```

I am not able to figure the cause of this error. How to fix it? Please help.

Also, is it the correct way of implementing the LSTM or is there a better way to achieve the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`torch.nn.LSTM` does not need any initialization, as it's initialized to zeros by default (see [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.LSTM)).
Furthermore, `torch.nn.Module` already has predefined `cuda()` method, so one can move module to GPU simply, hence you can safely delete `init_hidden(self, batch_size)`.

You have this error because your `input` is of type `torch.Double`, while modules by default use `torch.Float` (as it's accurate enough, faster and smaller than `torch.Double`).
You can cast your input Tensors by calling `.float()`, in your case it could look like that:

```
def forward(self, nn_input, hidden):
    nn_input = nn_input.float()
    ... # rest of your code
```

Finally, there is no need for `hidden` argument if it's always zeroes, you can simply use:

```
lstm_out, hidden = self.lstm(nn_input) # no hidden here
```

as `hidden` is zeroes by default as well.